# Examples and counterexamples in dimension theory

Tags: general-topology, dimension-theory-analysis

I am looking for examples of topological spaces that are interesting from a dimension theoretical point of view - in particular I am looking for these three notions of dimension:

1. Little inductive dimension,
2. big inductive dimension,
3. Lebesgue covering dimension.

I know that if a space is separable and metrizable, the three dimensions coincide but I am looking for simple cases where it does not.

I am also looking for examples of spaces (and their) where the monotonicity, sum and/or product theorem do not hold and various other interesting counterexamples where conditions are not satisfied (such as $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ being 0-dimensional subspaces of 1-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: Did you check Nagata's book on dimension theory?

Comment: @studiosus No, not yet. So far, I've been reading Hurewicz and Wallman's _Dimension theory_. It's a nice book but somewhat lacking in concrete examples.

Comment: That's a nice book but well behind Nagata's.

Comment: Also consider Engelking's book "Theory of dimensions, finite and infinite". This also discusses these examples. Some of them are very complex, but some are discussed, others only referenced. It's quite up to date (more even than Nagata's book).